# Using font in svg file

Tags: svg, fonts, styles

I am importing font in my svg file like this:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700,800');
  </style>
</defs>
```

But it looks like it is not working.
What can I doing wrong?

Can svg inherit styles from page, or should I import it in every page I have.
I actually rather like to have styles downloaded locally instead from googleapis, but looks like in this css file fonts are pointed relative to the server.
Can I do something with that?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code that **shows** it's not working? Right now you're showing a def, without any proof that you're even making use of it. That is not enough information for us to say anything sensible about.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xwgaae62/

Comment: Instead of a jsfiddle with what looks like thousands of lines of code, please put an [mcve] in your post. Reduce your problem to the bare minimum, because if it disappears while you do that, you solved your own problem without anyone's help already, and if it's still there, you know have precise code that doesn't waste any reader's time. Reduce your SVG to a simple svg doc with that def, a text element that is supposed to use that def, and perhaps a jsfiddle, or SO snippet, etc that shows it not loading *without* network errors showing in the dev tools due to CORS etc. violation